# Autocomplete in windows cmd prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, autocomplete

I know that we can autocomplete paths in cmd prompt. I just wanted to know if we can autocomplete commands in cmd prompt like we do in bash.
Can we make it search through a list of builtin commands and all executable(exe,bat,cmd etc..) files in the %PATH% when tab is pressed?
Or is there a shell-like software that is having this feature?

Comment: Only in the current directory ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [PromptPal](http://www.promptpal.com/)

Highly configurable, and provides full Windows-style editing, **command completion**, command history, syntax help, a tabbed interface and much more.

**Syntax Help**: As soon as a command is recognized, PromptPal displays helpful information about its parameters, switches and effects in a resizeable toolbar.

**Add You Own Commands**: If you have command line utilities that aren't recognized by PromptPal, that's no problem - it's easy to add them to PromptPal's collection.

$29.99 - 30 days trial

[image]

---

### [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell)

The new command shell and extensible automation engine from Microsoft does autocomplete commands.

It's native in windows 7 and Server 2008 R2.

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> > `powershell` > <kbd>Enter</kbd>

To install it on other windows: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929
And for more ressources about it: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419.aspx

---

### [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)

A Linux-like environment for Windows. It consists of two parts:

- A DLL (cygwin1.dll) which acts as a Linux API emulation layer providing substantial Linux API functionality.
- A collection of tools which provide Linux look and feel.

And so, a **bash shell** that does autocomplete

---

There's also [PowerCmd](http://www.powercmd.com/), It's a sort of GUI and not a shell replacement, so all the batch commands will be strictly the same.
It extends visually the autocomplete feature (but as far as I know, only with commands in the active directory). And it's a shareware: $29.95

Comment: Are you sure that powershell autocompletes commands.. I just tried it it didnt work for me... Can we make it work in xp? Thanx..

Comment: @nsharish yes it does, and yes you can install it on xp, look at my updated answer

Comment: Works for me here, I typed in 'disk' and hit tab and it cycled through a bunch of stuff that matched.

Comment: powershell doesn't accepts the same commands as the command prompt I think.

Comment: Yes.. Its working fine for powershell builtin cmdlets.. Only after the word is typed upto the hyphen.. I am not used to powershell cmdlets yet.. Thanx for a useful answer

Comment: Cygwin seems capable. But autocomplete is slow and it completes all files in the $PATH.. I'm learning to use powershell also. Thanx for the answer

Comment: @nsharish see my update, if you have some bucks to spend it could be a good solution...

Comment: It looks promising.. Trying it right away..

Comment: Can powercmd run without elevated privileges?

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegEdit to enable autocomplete on paths and files. Create a file called AutoCompleteChar.reg containing the following lines. Then invoke "regedit AutoCompleteChar.reg" to change autocomplete for paths and files to the tab (9) character. Works on Windows 10.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor]
"CompletionChar"=dword:00000009
"PathCompletionChar"=dword:00000009
```